# PHP filename parameter query

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

First of all I have checked the other suggested answers and I'm not certain whether they actually cover the question I've got.  I'm very new to PHP so please forgive me if I am asking what sounds like a stupid question.

**I have a php file which is called from another php file with a parameter**

I understand how this works in the calling file.

I don't understand how to extract the parameter contents into a variable at the target end.

Let's say for a moment that in the address bar of the browser I get this:

- targetfilename?parameter=Fred_hippy

I now want to pass "Fred" and "hippy" to a two-element array inside targetname.php.  That's it, nothing else.  (I said I was new to PHP.)

I think the way to do this is:

- $file = substr($targetfilename, 13);
- $name = explode("_", $file);

Is that correct please?  If not could somebody tweak it please?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if someone puts their name in as `Bob_`? It's technically a perfectly valid name. You'd probably be better off passing parameters through *"properly"* (e.g. `?name=Fred&lifestyle=Hippy` or whatever).

Comment: It was just a sample.  It could have been Mick or James or Dmitri ...

Comment: ... or `Mick_`, `_James` or `_Dmitry_` (note the underscores)? ;) If you concatenate data into a single querystring parameter and try and explode it later, someone, somewhere, will probably break it - deliberately or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All parameters (everything after the ?) are returned as $_GET or $_POST array. If you are typing into the address bar (as opposed to using a FORM) then it is always GET. PHP makes it really easy:

```
$parameter = $_GET['parameter'];
$name = explode("_",$parameter);
```

That leaves $name[0] = 'Fred' and $name[1] = 'hippy'.
In older versions of PHP, the $_GET to variable assignment was done automagically, which was very useful but also opened a lot of possible security issues, so that has been deprecated.

Another note based on comments. An alternative to:

```
targetfilename?parameter=Fred_hippy
```

is

```
targetfilename?name=Fred&status=hippy
```

which would be read in PHP as:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$status = $_GET['status'];
```

with no `explode()` needed. Basically, PHP understands the standard protocol for sending parameters via GET & POST and takes care of a lot of the details for you.

Comment: Thank you.  So obvious really.

Comment: @BarneyDouglas PHP has become a general purpose language (I use it in command line mode for some things) but it really started as a web site scripting language and the syntax & functions are optimized for that purpose. That is different from Python and some other languages where the language was already well established before it became heavily used for web sites so the web "stuff" is added on using various libraries and is not always so obvious or easy as with PHP.